# IE clears input[type="file"] on submit

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a page ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JGTHB/4/)):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#id_button").click(function(e) {
                    $("#id_file").click();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.google.com/">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="id_file" />
            <input type="button" id="id_button" value="fake button" />
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

if 
I open browse dialog via clicking "fake button", select file (I see it in `input[type="file"]`), than click submit button and no post happens, the `input[type="file"]` is cleared.

What should I changed to get it work?

I get this problem in IE8 and IE10.

PS: file input will be hidden, so user will work only with fake button.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cleared'. Do you mean IE removes the markup or do you mean it removes the selected file? If you have `display: none`, try changing that to `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: @JeevanJose IE removes selected file from file input.

Comment: Looks fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/JGTHB/5/

Comment: @JeevanJose no, after alert input is cleared. and focus set to it.

Answer (score 3):

All of the browsers have different behavior when it comes to what they allow you to do from javascript with regards to programmatically clicking the input button for file inputs.

The best solution I have found that seems to work cross browser is to set the opacity to 0 (do not use display:none) and put the button underneath the input, so the user clicks through the 0 opacity input to your button, thus firing the input select dialog.

A good writeup on styling the file input can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/j38Wj Works fine in Google Chrome but does not work in IE 10.
As I think IE does not allow select file by external 'click' event. 
Only one way to "customize" input[type=file] is usage of opacity style to hide it and relative positioning of custom button control below it.
Working example: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

```
[...]
```

Comment: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ looks realy cool I'll try it tomorrow, your jsfiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think all browser does that behaviour for security reason. When you submit a form, you are redirected to a different page(or the same page) and if you are directed to the same page, the form is re-initialized.
In this case, you simply can NOT set the value of file for security reason.

From example, [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html), you don't want this happen

```
<form name="foo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" value="c:\passwords.txt">
</form>
<script>document.foo.submit();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a label tag along with the input file element. Set the 'for' attribute of the label to the id of the input file element.

Then when you click on the label the input file element will 'click' and the file dialog will open.

Then simply style the label however you like. Have tried on various IE versions.